# "potentially dangerous Request.Form value"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting the error

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

when I deploy my application (the error does not happen when I run via localhost).

It occurs when submitting a form, because one of the fields contains HTML. I have added [AllowHtml] around the property in the model that corresponds to the offending form-field, but this does not seem to work.

I would rather not use [ValidateInput(false)] on the action method for obvious reasons, and at any rate, that doesn't seem to work either.

Is there any other configuration I need to be doing? I have read that adding

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

to the web config file could fix it, but again I don't want to add that because I still want secure validation for other parts of my application.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>`[AllowHtml]` requires you to add `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>` (setting this value doesn't mean that you don't get secure validation, it's just the validation mode). Other parts of the site will be secure, you are disabling validation only for the particular property on your view model.</strike>

`[ValidateInput(false)]` will work but as you said it might be less secure as it disables validation for all properties.

I would stick with `[AllowHtml]`.

---

UPDATE:

Both `[AllowHtml]` and `[ValidateInput(false)]` work out of the box in ASP.NET MVC 3 without the requirement of adding `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>` in web.config. This was necessary in ASP.NET MVC 2 running under ASP.NET 4.0

Here's an example:

View model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            Text = "<html/>"
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Text)
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

When the form is submitted no exception is thrown.

Comment: OK, so is using <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/> the only way to allow HTML to be submitted without the application complaining?

Comment: @MichaelS, as I said `[AllowHtml]` requires you to add it in order to work. The other way is to use the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute on your action.

Comment: It does not mention a requirement to add this in the XSS section of the following tutorial: http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer.aspx?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-security&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro which you can get to here: http://www.asp.net/mvc For the record, I am model-binding as it suggests in the video...

Comment: @MichaelS, I stand corrected. This was necessary in ASP.NET MVC 2 when running in ASP.NET 4. It is no longer needed in MVC 3. I will update my post.

Comment: @leppie, because what you call *duplicate question* was asked back in 2008 and you realize that things have changes a little since then, don't you? This question is about ASP.NET MVC 3 and back in 2008 no such beast was even planned to exist. It's not just because the titles of two questions resemble that this makes them duplicate. Their contents is also important and worth reading before voting to close a question.

Comment: @leppie, don't get me wrong if I know that there is a duplicate question I vote to close. The thing is that I don't always search whether a dupe exists before answering.

Comment: It would have been if you had taken the time to read it properly.